# Codeplex NDde Server how to send multiple items

Tags: .net, dde

Using NDde project (http://ndde.codeplex.com/) in vb.net server sample.  How to send multiple items?  Say item1, item2, etc.  Without success: Tried to copy and change the protected override functions from OnStartAdvise to all functions that affect 'item'.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Each item must be processed separately.