# NDde Server and Context for multiple Topics and Items. Do I need multiple instances?

Tags: c#, dde, ndde

I've checked out this question: [Codeplex NDde Server how to send multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218697/codeplex-ndde-server-how-to-send-multiple-items), and this [Alternative Of client.Advise += OnAdvise; in vb.net NDDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070650/alternative-of-client-advise-onadvise-in-vb-net-ndde), and a bunch of other sources, when dealing with this problem; however it seems that either I don't understand some basics, or it's something not explicitly supported in the way I have been trying to do it.

I'm struggling to write a class library that would send some values, about half-a-dozen, to an application that preferrably consumes DDE imputs, several at a time.

What is a source for perplexion for me is, whether I need to just do something like this, to be able to send my items by hot link

```
        public AutoServer(string service, string ItemDataLabel)
            : base(service)
        {
            // Create a timer that will be used to advise clients of new data.
            _Timer.Elapsed += this.OnTimerElapsed;
            _Timer.Interval = 30;
            _Timer.SynchronizingObject = this.Context;

            DataLabel = ItemDataLabel;
            //OnAdvise(Symbol, DataLabel, 1);
        }



        private void OnTimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
        {
            // Advise all topic name and item name pairs.

            OnAdvise(Current, DataLabel, 1);

            Advise(Current, DataLabel);
        }


        public string Data;
        public string DataLabel;
```

}

and put there in this fashion several OnAdvises with different string labels, writing out what On Advise should do in case with every label combination, inside OnAdvice itself?

The other option seems to register several Server instances, with writing out in OnAdvice all the details for each case of parameter combinations. 
But here comes the most difficult. I tried both approaches, and I'm getting exception that says: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created. In other words it comes out that I need a Context for each Server, respectively for each item (all that thing with multiple OnAdvices together doesn't seem to work).

Then would it be right to put form and context initialization in a single method with respective server registration, and so many likewise methods as the items are, and run them together at once?

For example:

```
namespace lookout_DDE
{
    public partial class lookout_DDE_class : AutoGroup
    {


        public partial class ServerContextForm : Form
        {
            private DdeContext context = null;

            private void ContextRunner()
            {
                context = new DdeContext(this);
                context.Initialize();
            }             
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace lookout_DDE
{
    public partial class lookout_DDE_class : AutoGroup
    {
        public partial class ServerContextForm : Form
        {
            public ServerContextForm()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                ContextRunner();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
        [STAThread]
        partial void RunServer()
        {

            using (ServerContextForm ContextForm = new ServerContextForm())
            {
                Application.Run(ContextForm);
                ServerStarter("A1");
            }
            using (ServerContextForm ContextForm = new ServerContextForm())
            {
                Application.Run(ContextForm);

                ServerStarter("A2");
            }
            using (ServerContextForm ContextForm = new ServerContextForm())
            {
                Application.Run(ContextForm);

                ServerStarter("A3");
            }
            using (ServerContextForm ContextForm = new ServerContextForm())
            {
                Application.Run(ContextForm);

                ServerStarter("A4");
            }
            using (ServerContextForm ContextForm = new ServerContextForm())
            {
                Application.Run(ContextForm);

                ServerStarter("A5");
            }
}
```

Just figured out I have to keep Forms for the contexts to run, so instead of \using\ separate methods would be needed.

So maybe the best way to restate the question would be, whether I need to use multiple forms with contexts, and server instances registered, in order to run multiple items, or somehow I should implement OnAdvice inside Server class?

See, I'm new to C# and programming in general, however, I'm trying to learn programming " in the process". If you can help, please advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Till now figured out partial solution:
1) There need to be several Server instances, because OnAdvice can be subscribed once by the client application. (And who knows how it does it if you didn't write it)
2) Each Server can require a separate (preferable) context, and respectively, a form, however there can be potentially a single context. Didn't test the last one.

Now, I recollected a bad/good joke about word "potentially". Guess what.
And what a pity of having no opinions at all!